# Issues with flexbox layout using div

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've added an image of what I'm trying to achieve. The existing code is in the jsfiffle link below.

I'm trying to turn the `<div class="grid 6 cheese_people_r">` into a flex box, it has two items inside it, The items in the flex box should be the image and the text. I would like the image on the right and the text on the left, they should be spaced so the text can be read and the image displays at a decent size. I've got to this point, but seem to have hot a wall. Any help welcome.

Please see jsfiddle for example

http://jsfiddle.net/UQSN4/4/

```
    <div class="grid 6 cheese_people_r">
        <li><img id="cheese_people_r" src="img/cheese_owner.jpg"><li>
        <li><p>The Big Cheese Owner <br/>  Sally Fiffle <br/> &ldquo;I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust. This has been done by our amazing staff and the products they produce. Nothing can replace dedication and pasion.&rdquo;</p><li>
    </div>
```

Comment: A picture of what you're looking for would help

Comment: Sorry, so now I have added the image of what the fiddle code is reflecting. You can see that at the moment the text is running over the image

Comment: You want the text to overflow the image?

Comment: Now try, and thanks! I want the text to align to the edge of the picture, not overflow over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/UQSN4/6/)

```
.cheese_people_r {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cheese_people_r {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it!

Comment: @Dano007 If that answer helped you you're supposed to accept it with the "V" button.

Comment: my only problem appears to be that using V1, the text appears below the actual picture. As per the image uploaded. How do I align the base of the etxt with the base of the image?

Comment: Didn't quite understand the problem

Comment: I've updated the image, I want to get the text moved up so it finishes in line with the bottom of the image.

Comment: You want the bottom of the text stick to the bottom of the image?

Comment: Like in the updated image example, which i mocked up in paint

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36986/discussion-between-itay-and-dano007)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you wanted something with `flex` box, so here you are.

I did write it from scratch, though, so your classes/ids are not present.

[**Version 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/UQSN4/12/): Does work in Firefox and Chrome, but due to lack of intrinsic width support in Safari/IE/Opera (non-chromium), won't display correctly there.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://s15.postimg.org/vl0o8vobf/cheese_owner.jpg"/></li>
    <li><h2>The Big Cheese Owner</h2>
        <h3>Sally Fiffle</h3>
        <p>&ldquo;I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust. This has been done by our amazing staff and the products they produce. Nothing can replace dedication and pasion.&rdquo;</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And some CSS

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #524c43;
}
ul {
    border: 2px solid #524c43;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
li {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.27;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    min-width: -webkit-min-content;
    min-width: -moz-min-content;
    min-width: min-content;
}
li img {
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

[**Version 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/UQSN4/11/): Using explicit widths, so it will at least look somewhat OK across browsers. Not as flexible, though.

```
<ul>
    <li style="max-width: 200px;"><img src="http://s15.postimg.org/vl0o8vobf/cheese_owner.jpg"/></li>
    <li style="max-width: 300px;"><h2>The Big Cheese Owner</h2>
        <h3>Sally Fiffle</h3>
        <p>&ldquo;I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust. This has been done by our amazing staff and the products they produce. Nothing can replace dedication and pasion.&rdquo;</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS is the same.

**Version 3** (which I recommend): Just don't `flex` boxes while the cross-browser support still isn't really there yet and use the hurt-free `float` version of @Itay.

Comment: Thanks very much for the time and effort to answer this.

Comment: Instead of a "thanks" (which is also appreciated nonetheless), try an upvote and/or accept either @Itay's or my answer, whichever you like better. ;)